# Automating Parameterization in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

My scripts have lot of dynamically changing variables for which I need to parametrize a lot. Is there any way with which we can automate or minimize the parametrization. I am using CSV & Regular Expression for parametrization. Any other ways to do the same??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CSV files with parameters as an input for your tests, you can define your input variables as properties. For example, if **customProperty** is defined in User Defined Variables section for your test plan (Test Plan, the top-1 element in your Jmeter scenario, not User Defined Variables sample), then you can access this value anywhere (even in different threads) by **${__P(customProperty)}**.

In this case, you should start Jmeter in the following way:

jmeter.bat   **-D**customProperty=customValue -t path\to\your\jmeter\scenario.jmx (for Windows machine).

It's pretty useful for automation goals(for example, if Jmeter is run by scheduler with -n option).

In case your parameters are generated within tests and you just looking for a way to pass them between your different threads without storing it in a file, properties are also useful. In opposite to User Defined Variables (that are processed on per-thread basis), the value stored as property can be accessed from any thread.

That's how you can do it:

1. Run initial request(s).
2. Extract variables from response   using Regular Expression Extractor.
3. Set extracted value as property with the following code in BeanShell Sampler: ${__setProperty(q, ${q})};
4. Use ${__P(q)} wherever you want.

Comment: This will be helpful if my input variables are known, but what if the value of variable is generated during run time. Eg - I am executing a sript for customer creation, where Customer ID is generated on submission of the details and the same Customer ID is used for processing the further functionality.